# iPhone App Development: Open app inside an app then edit

Tags: iphone, ios, iframe

Is there a way to make an app where you can open other app inside and can you edit the other apps style.

ex: Have an app which opens Safari inside the app (like iFrame in html) with other background color?

Is this possible in some way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Only one app runs at a time. One app can launch another app but you can't embed an app in another.

If you want to show a webpage inside an app, you can use a `UIWebView`.

Answer (score 0):

Only possible if the original app has been designed to have that functionality (so you can write two apps that interact with each other, but to 'edit' another maker's app would require them writing all possible 'edit' values in a shared preference file)

You could 'open safari' in another app with uiwebview and design the interface yourself.